# SUM values - output error when de sum is equal to zero

Tags: mysql, sum, prepared-statement

With the following query I get the sum of the sales value per year for each country in the database

```
   $country_parameter = $_REQUEST['parameter'];

   $query = "SELECT YEAR(sl.year_sales) AS year,
                       COALESCE(SUM(sl.value_sales),0) AS value
                       FROM sales sl LEFT JOIN country co
                       ON sl.id_country = co.id_country
                       WHERE parameter = ?
                       GROUP BY year
                       ORDER BY year";

    if($statement = $conexao->prepare($query)){
        $statement->bind_param("i", $country_parameter );
        $statement->execute();

        $result = $statement ->get_result();

        while($data = $result->fetch_assoc()){
            $output[] = $data;
        }

        echo json_encode($output);

    $conexao->close();
```

Problem: when there are no sales and the sum is equal to zero, on the client side the output returns only **null** and I get de error *Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'metaData' of null*

EDITED:

If value the output is:

```
[{"year":2017,"value":11600}]
```

If not output is just:

```
null
```

If I query the database directly the result is:

year:

value:

Is the year supposed to always return a result and the value equal zero?

year: 2016

value: 0

Comment: So you're saying if the year is 1900 and there are no sales for Mexico; the you have no record and that throws an error?

Comment: Yes is that xQbert.

Comment: I edited my post.

Answer (score 0):

Best way to get rid of the error is by checking the that the country parameter is set so do an if statement after the declaration of $country_parameter like this

```
$country_parameter = //value;
if (!isset($country_parameter)==0){
// do something 
}
```

Comment: I checked and the $country_parameter always has a numeric value corresponding to a particular country.